# Paypal accept payments in INR

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using paypal standard payment system to accept payment from my customers. I've made INR as primary in my paypal account.But it gives the error when I pass currency code as INR. I've already referred about this issue with some websites including,

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/Accepting-Indian-currency/td-p/615019
Here is my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_link; ?>" method="POST">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_username; ?>">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="INR">

    <!-- Specify URLs -->
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://.....'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http:....'>


    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

Can anybody help to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: code updated ..

Comment: What error are you getting and is that a business PayPal account or personal?

Answer (score 0):

Please check it which payment method you have purchased. Ex:(DoDirect, ExpressCheckout).
Particular payment method supported the INR. Review everything.

Comment: I'm using Paypal Standard payment  gateway integration which also supports INR?

Comment: I think it's not supported. Review below url https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#variations-on-basic-variables

Comment: This also https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I think it's been supported now.